# Cómo modificar la propiedad Description en un Panel SD?

Tags: genexus

Cómo se puede modificar la propiedad Description de un Panel SD en tiempo de ejecucion?

En tiempo de diseño colocamos una descripcion para el PanelSD, pero en tiempo de ejecucion
queremos modificar ese titulo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaría con "form.caption=&Titulo", más información https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4633,Caption+property

Answer (score 0):

Probé desde el evento Refresh del PanelSD, y funcionó

Form.Caption = "Descripcion dinamica: " + &Mivariable.Trim()